# Are method References as method parameters thread safe in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, method-reference

i have the following scenario:

```
interface ValueBinding<T> {
    public void setValue(T input);
}

public enum FacesBinding {
    VALUE;
    public void bindString(ValueBinding<String> fcn, HttpServletRequest req, String param){
        try {
            String val = req.getParameter(param);
            if( val != null )
                fcn.setValue(val);
        } catch (Exception e) { }        
    }
    public void bindBoolean(ValueBinding<Boolean> fcn, HttpServletRequest req, String param){
        try {
            fcn.setValue(req.getParameter(param) != null);
        } catch (Exception e) { }        
    }
    public void bindInt(ValueBinding<Integer> fcn, HttpServletRequest req, String param){
        try {
            int val = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter(param));
            fcn.setValue(val);
        } catch (Exception e) { }        
    }
    public void bindLong(ValueBinding<Long> fcn, HttpServletRequest req, String param){
        try {
            long val = Long.parseLong(req.getParameter(param));
            fcn.setValue(val);
        } catch (Exception e) { }        
    }
...
...
}
```

and i use it in a "multithreaded" Environment like this:

**concurrent Threads are calling this method**

```
            @Override // concurrent Threads are calling this method
            public Category initData(FacesContext facesContext) throws Exception {
                Category entity = new Category();
                HttpServletRequest req = facesContext.getRequest();
                FacesBinding.VALUE.bindLong(entity::setId, req, Table.Category.Field.ID.name());
                FacesBinding.VALUE.bindString(entity::setName, req, Table.Category.Field.NAME.name());

                FacesBinding.VALUE.bindInt(entity::setPosition, req, Table.Category.Field.POSITION.name());
                FacesBinding.VALUE.bindBoolean(entity::setLocalized, req, Table.Category.Field.LOCALIZED.name());           
                return entity;
            }
```

is

`FacesBinding.VALUE.bindLong(entity::setId, req, Table.Category.Field.ID.name());`

**100% Thread safe** when i pass a **method reference**(interface) `entity::setId` as parameter of a method in **enum** Object (Singleton)?

NOTE:

```
entity::setId

entity::setName

entity::setPosition
```

...etc. ALL these methods are standard java setter methods

```
public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
....
```

**UPDATE:**

to be concrete: 
**ARE**

```
Category entity = new Category();
entity.setId(5);//thread safe for sure
```

**100% equal to**

```
FacesBinding.VALUE.bindLong(entity::setId, ...);
```

does the fact that `FacesBinding` ist Singleton and the method Reference in `bindLong(entity::setId, ...)` makes it thread-unsafe??

Comment: I don't see what could render this thread safe. But this deserve some research

Comment: @AxelH, isn't the fact that the method bindLong(entity::setId, ...) takes a method of a new Instance of the Object (new Category() in my case) makes it thread safe?

Answer (score 2):

Your method reference call will be thread-safe if your `setId` method is thread-safe, nothing more and nothing less.

Method reference is a fancy shorthand for creating your `ValueBinding` objects. When they are compiled, there will be a private inner class of sorts that implements your functional interface and calls the method you specified. Since you specified method that belongs to an object, this inner class will also be *equivalent to* having constructor that accepts your `Category` object, and a private field to store it (I said equivalent to because by default implementations are not limited to this behavior if they can justify and choose any other).

Comment: setId method is a usual java setter method, since it belongs to a particular instance of the Category Object, is thread safe. does this mean that my implementation above 100% thread safe despite the fact that i use it as methode reference in Singleton object (enum)?

Comment: I would say that having it as a simple setter will rather make it **not** thread safe, because by thread safety you usually mean ordered writes, and since there is no synchronization in place neither on "ValueBinding" nor on "setId", and with added fact that any of your ValueBinding objects can be shared by several concurrent threads at discretion of its use-site.

Comment: in my case the concurrent Threads are calling the initData(..) method. as you see inside this methode, i create a new instance of my Category Object. No thread has any direct access to the setter methods. every call of initData(..) become a new Instance. this is why i said its thread safe. But i am not sure if this the case by using method references in an enum Object. here are my worries.

Comment: In your particular situation, you indeed may consider your initData(FC) method to be thread safe, since it does not (as far as I can tell) use any values that another thread may also use. In terms of functions, your initData can be considered "pure" since it only depends on its input and not on some outside mutable state. However, I will still stand by my initial judgements: entity::getId is not thread-safe itself. It is just used in a thread-safe manner (i.e. there are no cases where several threads can access the same instance of entity::getId).

Comment: thank you very much Mikhail, actually i agree with all what you said. But i will wait to see what others say about that.

Comment: Just a side note about Method References in Java 8, they are utilized as a functional interface, but they don't compile down to a private inner class.  They compile down to an opcode that was added in Java 7 called invokedynamic that initially bootstraps and creates a dynamic linkage between the call and the code that is to be executed.  After that initial call, the opcode is then read as invokestatic, so it is extremely efficient.

Comment: @CraigR8806, do they actually compile into invokestatic though? As far as I remember, method reference compiles into an equivalent of both private static method and an invokedynamic that points at that method and has encoded expected type information. Those types of invokedynamic then picked up by resolver and turned into an anonymous class that only then has an invokestatic opcode that points to private method. I was not aware that it's possible to link that method directly, can you please point to where you learnt it from?

Comment: @CraigR8806, to think about it, maybe invokestatic is linked for case when method reference is not capturing (i.e. an instance method with no parameters). Is that it?

Comment: @Mikhail Prokhorov: it’s actually the opposite. If the method reference is not capturing (i.e. has the form `TypeName::methodName`), the `invokedynamic` instruction will be linked to a pseudo method that always returns the same function instance. When it is capturing (the `expression::methodName` form), it will link to a `static` factory method that will instantiate a new function object on each call. This is not the target method of the reference (`methodName`), which is usually not `static` in this case anyway. They could link to a constructor instead; that’s a minor implementation detail.

Comment: But there seems to be a bit of confusion about these methods anyway. Lambda expressions get compiled to `private` methods, always `static` if they don’t capture `this`, but might still be `static`, if they capture this (and get `this` as an ordinary parameter), that’s up to the compiler. The class synthesized at runtime will invoke that method, whether `static` or not. Likewise, it may directly invoke a target method of a method reference or even a constructor directly. Only for some rare cases, e.g. `ArrayType::new` or varargs methods, method reference get compiled like a lambda expressions.