# is method reference of constructor thread safe in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, constructor

for example, here is a class `A`, `FunciontionInterface f= A::new`, then I call f() in different threads, is it thread safe?

note: this is not a duplicate question of [Are method References as method parameters thread safe in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41896724/are-method-references-as-method-parameters-thread-safe-in-java) . Furthermore, I am asking the constructor method of objects, not a user-defined method.

Comment: Sure, method references are just objects, they aren't bound to a specific thread. And constructors themselves are thread-safe because you can never be calling a constructor twice to construct the same object instance.

Comment: @user207421 why cannot I call a constructor twice? I can event call it in different thread at the same time.

Comment: You can call it twice but you will be constructing two different objects, not the same object. You might have to worry about synchronization for static members but not for instance members. Unless `this` escapes the constructor.

Comment: You can kind of construe object creation as `A a = (new A).A();`.

Comment: Could you explain what you assume may happen in terms of thread safety? If the question is just that general I guess then @user207421 has said all there is to say.

Answer (score 3):

Method references are just syntactic sugar. Thread safety of method references (in this case constructor references) boils down to the fact if the constructor is thread safe itself. Situations when constructors are not thread safe are for example :

- modifying `static` variable from within a constructor without proper synchronization mechanism
- publishing `this` reference from within constructor before the object is fully initialized and can be accessed by other threads.

To add more, if you invoke a constructor in some method (does not matter if this is done through normal constructor call or a method reference to this constructor) then the object, that is created, is bound to this thread (thread confinement) and if you do not let the reference to this object escape - then the object created is used by only one Thread.

Answer (score 3):

A method reference is a value.  We can't say whether it's thread-safe or not thread-safe.   Any more than we can say whether the value `3.14159` is thread-safe or not thread-safe.

If you put a method reference in a shared variable, then the thread-safety depends on how the shared variable is used.  Just like any other variable.

If you invoke (call) a method reference then thread-safety depends on how the method / constructor has been implemented.  The implementation can be thread safe or not.

Possible reasons for a constructor to be non-thread-safe *include*:

- using a shared static variable without synchronization
- publishing `this` before it has been completely initialized (unsafe publication)
- the constructor calling a method on some other object that is not thread-safe.

---

> I am asking the constructor method of objects, not a user-defined method.

There is no difference between ordinary methods and constructors.

Note that both methods and constructors are user defined ... except for the default no-args constructor.  (And even the latter will be non-thread-safe if its superclasses constructor it not thread-safe.)